# Determine maximal number of "parallel execution agents" in the parallel STL

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17

Is there a way to know a maximal number of parallel execution agents (not sure what the term is) in the parallel STL algorithms?

The reason I need this information is to pre-allocate memory needed by the function.

I.e. I want to parallelize the following code without allocating too much/too little memory:

```cpp
template<std::ranges::range Rng>
void foo(int n, Rng& rng)
{
    const std::size_t required_dynamic_size_per_call = something_manually_calculated(n);
    std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource rsc(std::pmr::pool_options{??? * required_dynamic_size_per_call, required_dynamic_size_per_call} );
    
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(rng), std::end(rng), [&](auto i)
    {
        some_heavy_computation(&rsc, i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `required_dynamic_size_per_thread`? because `per_iteration` is simple: `std::size(rng)`

Comment: @Caleth I meant this size to be what is required by `some_heavy_computation` _per call_. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How do you expect to hand out these resources? Whether a worker thread or the main thread does the work is unspecified, and how many threads are involved is also unspecified. Is there some reason you can't just do: `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource rsc(required_dynamic_size_per_call);` *inside* the lambda, so each one has its own? The docs are pretty clear that: 1) `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` is not thread-safe, and 2) Even if you pass it an explicit size, it doesn't initially allocate anything (just sets `next_size`), so you'd *definitely* race on the allocation when first used.

Comment: Even if it was thread-safe, there seems no obvious way to use it that your use case would benefit from. Each separate task would need to call `do_allocate`, would get their own memory, and that memory could never be reused (because no other task could find it, and monotonic allocators' `do_deallocate` is a no-op), and it would only be cleaned up when the resource was freed at the very end.  Whether you used 12 threads or just 1, it would still have to allocate memory proportionate to the number of tasks.

Comment: Regardless, to the actual question: C++ parallelism is *extremely* light on details. To my knowledge there is no standards-compliant way to determine *if* threads will be used, let alone how many. You *suggest* allowing threads, and its entirely up to the runtime whether it uses them and how it does so.

Comment: @ShadowRanger afaict it's left up to the implementation-defined optional additional policies to handle those details.

Comment: @Caleth: Sure. That means the question is unanswerable for portable code, and unanswerable even for non-portable code unless the OP can specify their OS, compiler, C++ runtime, etc. If you think you need this sort of detail: 1) You probably don't, and 2) If you really do, you probably have a case where C++ standard parallelism isn't adequate for your needs, and you need to shift to using a parallelism solution with more knobs (e.g. OpenMP).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I edited the `memory_resource` to something that conveys the logic, my mistake (I'm new to `std::pmr`, hope I got it right this time). As for your answer _it can't be done portably_ - it is a shame as this seems like a very simple use case and now I need to use concurrency and complicate the code for a very simple task.

Comment: @OmerRosler: C++ only began describing threading as part of the standard in C++11 (the memory model didn't even account for threading until then, so technically, *any* use of threading was implementation-defined at best). They've been *very* cautious about what they add, to avoid putting constraints on implementations, and to avoid locking in decisions that may be unwise in hindsight (since undoing them is hard to the point of being nearly impossible unless it's completely broken or the fix is compatible with 99.99% of existing code).

Comment: I'd contest the characterization as "a very simple use case", given, even without threads involved, it's rather rare for even performance-sensitive C++ code to resort to separate, dedicated, presized memory pools. Worst case scenario here, your code has to expand the pools as it runs based on demand, which (assuming amortized growth patterns) is not terrible. You could guess a presize bound based on a heuristic like `std::min(std::size(rng), std::max(std::thread::hardware_concurrency()), 1))` or somesuch, where you assume it will use a thread per core; if you're wrong, it'll resize for you.